# How to create a custom MUI-Datatables search box with outlined style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Default UI from MUI-Datatables v4.3.0 like this :
[image]

And i'am want to make this style :
[image]

For information i am using this package :
"@mui/material": "^5.11.4"
"mui-datatables": "^4.3.0"

How to make The TextField or Input with outlined style.

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#basic-textfield
It can help you:
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />

Comment: How to implement into MUI-Datatables Search Box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of example MUI-Databales from this link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gregnb/mui-datatables
I have a answer and solution from my case.

My Component CustomSearchRender.js :

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import Grow from "@mui/material/Grow";
> import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
> import { withStyles } from "tss-react/mui";
> import { SearchOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
> import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
>
> const defaultSearchStyles = (theme) => ({
>   searchText: {
>     flex: "0.8 0",
>     marginTop: 10,
>   },
>   searchIcon: {
>     "&:hover": {
>       color: theme.palette.error.main,
>     },
>   },
> });
>
> const CustomSearchRender = (props) => {
>   const { classes, onSearch, searchText } = props;
>   const handleTextChange = (event) => {
>     onSearch(event.target.value);
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <Grow appear in={true} timeout={300}>
>       <TextField
>         placeholder="Search"
>         size="medium"
>         className={classes.searchText}
>         value={searchText || ""}
>         onChange={handleTextChange}
>         fullWidth
>         variant="outlined"
>         InputProps={{
>           startAdornment: (
>             <InputAdornment position="start">
>               <SearchOutlined />
>             </InputAdornment>
>           ),
>         }}
>       />
>     </Grow>
>   );
> };
>
> export default withStyles(CustomSearchRender, defaultSearchStyles, {
>   name: "CustomSearchRender",
> });
> ```

And put into options :

```
const options = {
    selectableRows: "none",
    filterType: "textField",
    responsive: "simple",
    confirmFilters: false,
    jumpToPage: false,
    download: false,
    print: false,
    enableNestedDataAccess: ".",
    textLabels: {
      body: {
        noMatch: loading ? (
          <TableSkeleton variant="h4" length={10} />
        ) : (
          "Maaf, tidak ada data untuk ditampilkan"
        ),
      },
    },
    searchOpen: true,
    searchAlwaysOpen: true,
    searchPlaceholder: "Search keyword",
    customSearchRender: (searchText, handleSearch) => {
      return (
        <CustomSearchRender searchText={searchText} onSearch={handleSearch} />
      );
    },
  };
```

And finnally the result like this :
[image]